# How to interpret Lorentz transformation and synchronized clocks?

Tags: special-relativity

I'll use the familiar train/embankment example to set up my question. I'll also number my steps to make it easy to debug.

1. A train is moving relative to the embankment at a constant speed v.
2. There are synchronized clocks everywhere on the train and the embankment.
3. When the train's origin coincides with the embankment's origin, both the train's clock at the origin and the embankment's clock at the origin point to 0.
4. For simplicity, assume that v = 40 meter/second and c = 100 meter/second, where c is the speed of light.
5. Consider the point (10, 0) relative to the embankment. The corresponding position and time relative to the train, after Lorentz transformation, is approximately (10.91, -0.04).
6. My interpretation of 5 is: when the 10 meter mark on the embankment coincides with the 10.91 meter mark on the train, the clock at the 10 meter mark on the embankment points to 0, and the clock at the 10.91 meter mark on the train points to -0.04.
7. On the other hand, when the clock at the 10 meter mark on the embankment points to 0, the clock at the origin of the embankment should also point to 0, by 2.
8. When the clock at the origin of the embankment points to 0, the clock at the origin of the train should also point to 0, by 3.
9. But when the clock at the origin of the train points to 0, the clock at the 10.91 meter mark on the train should also point to 0, by 2, contradicting to 6, which requires the clock at the 10.91 meter mark on the train to be pointing to -0.04.

What am I missing?

Comment: Right from the beginning (well, item (2)) you've under-specified the situation. In what manner are the two sets of clocks (those on the embankment and those on the train) synchronized? In point (3) you tells us how two particular clocks are related, but you never say how the rest are related to those two. Then you make a lot of claims about what the clocks "should" read. So, if you specify exactly what you mean in item (2) you should be able to find where your logic is failing.

Comment: @dmckee, take two clocks on the embankment, A and B. Let M be the midpoint between A and B. Let A and B send a light signal to M when each strikes say, t seconds. A and B are synchronized if M receives these signals at the same time, for any t. Same definition for clocks on the train.

Comment: Surely you can see that you *can't* have more than two clocks all mutually synchronized under that definition. And pointedly it is not consistent with the definition that Einstein used (search term "Einstein synchronization"), which means that you wouldn't expect to be able to understand Einstein's thought experiments on the basis of your method.

Comment: @dmckee, take two clocks on the embankment, A and B. Assume that they are synchronized as defined in my last comment. I'll try to show that they are also synchronized in the sense of Einstein synchronization. Let clock A send a light signal to clock B when clock A points to t(A). Clock B, upon receiving the signal at local time t(B), sends a signal back to clock A, which is received by clock A at local time t'(A).I need to show that t(B) = (t(A) + t'(A))/2. Let M be the midpoint between A and B. Let the distance between A and M be x meters. I'll do it in 4 steps.

Comment: 1. Let a clock that is x meters away from M send a signal to M at local time t, let the signal then be reflected back to the clock from M, then the clock will point to t + dt, regardless of whether the clock is A or B.

Comment: 2. Let clock A and clock B send each other a light signal, when each points to local time t, respectively. Then clock A will receive the signal from clock B at local time t + dt, and clock B will receive the signal from clock A at local time t + dt as well. This step follows from combining 1 with the assumption that A and B are synchronized as defined in my last comment.

Comment: 3. Let A and B send each other a signal at local time t(A), i.e. A sends B a signal when A points to t(A), and B sends A a signal when B points to t(A). Then t(B) = t(A) + dt, where t(B) is the local time of clock B unpon receiving the signal from clock A. Also, clock A receives the signal from B at local time t(B) as well. This step follows from 2 by substituting t = t(A).

Comment: 4. Let A and B send each other a signal at local time t(B). Then t'(A) = t(B) + dt, where t'(A) is the local time of clock A upon receiving the signal from clock B. This step follows from 2 by substituting t = t(B). Now t(B) = (t(A) + t'(A))/2 by combining 3 and 4.

Comment: Now add a third clock...

Comment: @dmckee, I don't have enough reputation to create a chat room. I want to follow up with this conversation but I also want to avoid extended discussions in comments.